# GitLab: Docker in Docker container can't connect to Service container

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-in-docker, clair

My GitLab CI/CD has a `service` image named `clair-db`, but my main job's image (`docker:19.03.6` can't seem to communicate with it.  I have reviewed the [GitLab Service's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-services-are-linked-to-the-job), which claims you can connect your build's main image to a service by simply using the service's name as the hostname and its exposed port (for example, a service named `mysql:latest` with an exposed port `1234` would allow you to connect to it as `mysql:1234` -- meaning `ping mysql:1234` would work successfully).

Interestingly, I **can** `ping` the service i'm trying to communicate with (which is `arminc-clair-db:5432`) within the GitLab CI/CD build with the following command:

```sh
$ export LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS=arminc-clair-db
$ ping -c 4 $LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS:5432
PING arminc-clair-db:5432 (172.17.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.106 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
--- arminc-clair-db:5432 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.074/0.087/0.106 ms
```

But trying to communicate with `arminc-clair-db:5432` fails in the following command:

```sh
$ docker run --interactive --rm --volume "$PWD":/tmp/app -e CI_PROJECT_DIR=/tmp/app -e CLAIR_DB_CONNECTION_STRING="postgresql://postgres:password@${LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS}:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable&statement_timeout=60000" -e CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=[MASKED]/codigo-initiative -e CI_APPLICATION_TAG=latest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar

Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar:latest
[INFO] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:50:54Z] ▶ GitLab klar analyzer v2.4.8
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:50:54Z] ▶ Allowlist file with path '/tmp/app/clair-whitelist.yml' does not exist, skipping
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:50:54Z] ▶ Allowlist file with path '/tmp/app/vulnerability-allowlist.yml' does not exist, skipping
[INFO] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:50:54Z] ▶ DOCKER_USER and DOCKER_PASSWORD environment variables have not been configured. Defaulting to DOCKER_USER=$CI_REGISTRY_USER and DOCKER_PASSWORD=$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:50:54Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 1 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:50:56Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 2 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:50:58Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 3 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:00Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 4 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:02Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 5 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:04Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 6 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:06Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 7 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:08Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 8 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:10Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 9 of 10
[WARN] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:13Z] ▶ Vulnerabilities database not ready, waiting 2s before retrying. Retry 10 of 10
[FATA] [klar] [2020-07-12T17:51:15Z] ▶ error while waiting for vulnerabilities database to start. Giving up after 10 retries.: dial tcp: lookup arminc-clair-db on 169.254.169.254:53: no such host
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Below is my full `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages: 
  - scan

scanning:
  stage: scan
  image: docker:19.03.6
  services:
    - name: arminc/clair-db:latest
    - name: docker:19.03.6-dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
  script:
    - export LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS=arminc-clair-db
    - ping -c 4 $LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS:5432 #Pinging 'arminc-clair-db:5432' to prove that it IS accessible
    - docker run --interactive --rm --volume "$PWD":/tmp/app -e CI_PROJECT_DIR=/tmp/app -e CLAIR_DB_CONNECTION_STRING="postgresql://postgres:password@${LOCAL_MACHINE_IP_ADDRESS}:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable&statement_timeout=60000" -e CI_APPLICATION_REPOSITORY=vismarkjuarez1994/codigo-initiative -e CI_APPLICATION_TAG=latest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/klar
```

I've also referred to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316098/connecting-to-docker-in-docker-from-a-gitlab-ci-runner?noredirect=1&lq=1) to no avail.