# how to connect golang in gitlab to mongodb container in gitlab-ci

Tags: mongodb, go, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to connect my golang code (without a container) to the monogdb container, when it is local it works.

when I push it to gitlab.ci using container, connection refused

previously I used to use testing in dockerfile, but I don't use that.

the code is like this

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - test

variables:
  REPO_NAME: $REPO_URL
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2


test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apk add go make bash docker-compose
    # - make service-up-test
  script:
    - make mongodb-test-up
    - go clean -testcache && go test -v ./app/test
```

and golang test :

```golang
package codetify

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

var credential = options.Credential{
    Username: "usernametest",
    Password: "passwordtest",
}
var addr = "mongodb://0.0.0.0:27018"

func InitMongoDB() *mongo.Database {
    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(addr).SetAuth(credential)
    clientOpts.SetDirect(true)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("client", client)
        return nil
    }
    return client.Database("databasetest")
}

func TestPingMongoDBServer(t *testing.T) {
    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(addr).SetAuth(credential)
    clientOpts.SetDirect(true)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOpts)
    assert.Equal(t, err, nil, "Shoudl be not error")
    err = client.Ping(context.Background(), readpref.Primary())
    assert.Equal(t, err, nil, "Shoudl be not error")
}
```

Comment: Hello Fajrul, could you share some more details like where mongodb is running and the full error message? The connection error is happening in that test code you shared right?

Comment: this is reality: `*errors.errorString(&errors.errorString{s:"server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: 0.0.0.0:27018, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp 0.0.0.0:27018: connect: connection refused }, ] }"})`, not expected, but I think, this problem  not from golang or docker, this is problem in gitlab.ci, I want to connect to mongoDB container from my code in giltlab.ci runner

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316098/connecting-to-docker-in-docker-from-a-gitlab-ci-runner might be of help

Answer (score 0):

[Next]

this is a docker-compose.yml for mongodb, for testing, i use another port

```
version: '3'
services: 
    database:
        image:  'mongo:latest'
        container_name: '${APP_NAME}-mongodb-test'
        environment: 
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: usernametest
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: passwordtest
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: databasetest
        command: mongod
        ports:
            - '27018:27017'
        restart: always
        volumes: 
            - ./resources/mongo-initdb.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-initdb.js
        networks: 
            - codetify-net-test
networks: 
    codetify-net-test
```

Comment: Did this get it to work, or did you mean to add this to your original post?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the exact same right now and I get the same issue